# Strange properties of int

Tags: javascript, java, c

In one of his talks Douglas Crockford says, int have some strange properties and he goes ahead and explains,
It is possible to have two integers a and b, such that a > 0, b > 0.

```
c = a + b
```

And we can end up with a c possibly c < a or b < a.
Can someone explain this with an example.

This is a screenshot from his talk.
[image]

Comment: Not in JavaScript, no. (As there are no integers in JS anyway). Can you please point to the talk where he said this, to give some context?

Comment: This only will be true if addition results in an overflow, but I highly doubt it in the case of Javascript.

Comment: @Bergi Talk was The good parts of javascript. And you are right it's not possible in javascript, it's in languages that support int as a seperate type.

Comment: In that case, he's referring to [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) that happens for fixed-width integer represetations.

Comment: *"Good that we don't have int"* is a misleading sentence: It's not the integer data type that is the problem. It's possible to have C implementation where overflow never happens, but many implementations choose not to as it's more faster that way due to hardware limitations.

Answer (score 2):

In [c](/questions/tagged/c) there is a scenario which can lead to this kind of behavior.(For example: signed integer addition etc) Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior. Evaluation of an expression produces undefined behavior if the result is not a representable value of the expression's type. On many machines the undefined behavior turns out to be the fact - that it will turn `c` negative (talking in context of signed addition). This is signed integer overflow. An example must be something like

```
int a = INT_MAX;
int b = INT_MAX;
int c = a + b; //<--- overflow.
```

Digging a bit further it is clear that overflow behavior is getting fixed to the max value of the type in case of [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). So the scenario you showed is most probably not of [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

In [java](/questions/tagged/java) when it overflows it goes back to the minimum value and start from there. For underflow the same happens but only the maximum value is reached and then it goes from there.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible because the overflow condition in addition operation is not handled properly.
Say in a system int takes 2 bytes of space.
so the range supported is -32768 to +32767 or 0 to 65535

```
a=65534,b=4; 
c=a+b;
c=3.

b=65534,a=4; 
c=a+b;
c=3.
```

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that computer integers cannot model mathematics exactly when they overflow, or to otherwise phase this. Whether the handling is “proper” or not is a value judgement—if the behavior works for a particular application, even most applications, and is used appropriately, and is a fast, economic solution, then it is proper. It is a tool that served its purpose. The fact that it has limits does not make it bad; all tools have limits.